# Golang - Date Parsing a YYYY-MM-DD date

Tags: date, go

Hi so I can't seem to find anything to help me on this.

I am using the format string
"January 02, 2006"
and the time string
"2016-07-08"

However when I run a format using these parameters the response I get is July 7th, 2016. The correct response would be July 8th, 2016.

As a note, I am also trying to use this via Sprig.

```
{{ date "January 02, 2006" .MyDate }}
```

If I can get any assistance it would be much appreciated

Comment: It could be an issue with Time Zone conversion to UTC

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because of the time zone, you're getting the right date, but `sprig` formats to **"Local"** by default, where `golang.org/pkg/time` defaults to **"UTC"**

Here is a sample code: *(omitting error handling for simplicity)*

```
func main() {
    // using the "time" package
    mydate, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2016-07-08")
    fmt.Println("time:", mydate.In(time.Local).Format("January 02, 2006 (MST)"), "-- specify Local time zone")
    fmt.Println("time:", mydate.Format("January 02, 2006 (MST)"), "-- defaults to UTC")

    d := struct{ MyDate time.Time }{mydate}

    //using sprig
    fmap := sprig.TxtFuncMap()
    localTpl := `sprig: {{ date "January 02, 2006 (MST)" .MyDate }} -- defaults to Local`
    t := template.Must(template.New("test").Funcs(fmap).Parse(localTpl))
    var localdate bytes.Buffer
    t.Execute(&localdate, d)
    fmt.Println(localdate.String())

    utcTpl := `sprig: {{ dateInZone "January 02, 2006 (MST)" .MyDate "UTC"}} -- specify UTC time zone`
    t = template.Must(template.New("test").Funcs(fmap).Parse(utcTpl))
    var utcdate bytes.Buffer
    t.Execute(&utcdate, d)
    fmt.Println(utcdate.String())

}
```

**Output:**

```
time:  July 07, 2016 (EDT) -- specify Local time zone                                                                                  
time:  July 08, 2016 (UTC) -- defaults to UTC                                                                                          
sprig: July 07, 2016 (EDT) -- defaults to Local                                                                                        
sprig: July 08, 2016 (UTC) -- specify UTC time zone
```

Here is some reference:

**time**: https://golang.org/pkg/time

> In the absence of a time zone indicator, Parse returns a time in UTC.

**spig**: https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/master/functions.go#L407

```
func date(fmt string, date interface{}) string {
    return dateInZone(fmt, date, "Local")
}
```

**Note:** if you want to format to a specific time zone, look at the 2nd template:

```
utcTpl := `sprig: {{ dateInZone "January 02, 2006 (MST)" .MyDate "UTC"}} -- specify UTC time zone`
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was in depth and useful. Sorted out my problem due to this. Resulting code:
{{ dateInZone "January 02, 2006 (MST)" .Date "UTC"}}
Thank you - I have no idea how to mark your question as the answer thought :S.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. Good luck :) .. I see you marked it already.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct way is to send `time.Time` type to your template and then use `Format` function on it. You can use `ParseTime` to parse your `2016-07-08` format.

```
type Data struct {
    CreatedOn time.Time
}

template.Execute(w, Data{})
```

Template:

```
<span>{{ .CreatedOn.Format "January 02, 2006" }}</span>
```